# Doctrine querybuilder multiple where

Tags: php, api, doctrine-orm

I have a problem that I have trouble going through.

I am building an API where you can filter the request with different values using PHP slim.

```
$app->get('/stats/getCrash/:dqaid(/:portal', function ($dqaid, $portal = null) use ($app) {
    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    $app->response->setBody(json_encode(APIResult::test($dqaid, $portal)));
    $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

My function where I am trying to make the query :

```
     /**
     * @param $filters CrashFilters
     */
    public static function test($dqaid, $filters){
        $em = DBConnection::getEntityManager();

        $whereClause = CrashFilters::getWhereClause($dqaid, $filters);

        $response = $em->createQuery("select c from crashes c $whereClause")->getResult();

    print_r($response);
}
```

My class where I stock the filters and I create the where close.

```
class CrashFilters
{
    private $app_id = "null";
    private $reason = "null";
    private $app_version_id = "null";
    private $reash_hash = "null";
    private $brand = "null";
    private $model = "null";
    private $os_version = "null";
    private $portal = "null";
    private $datecreated = "null";

/**
     * @param $filters CrashFilters
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getWhereClause($dqaid, $filters){
        $result = ' WHERE dqaid='."'".$dqaid."'";
        foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
            if ($value != "null") {
                $result .= ' AND ';
                $result .= "$key='" . $value . "' ";
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

I want to have a query that execute a select and filter by the parameter set by the user.

How could I do it ?

Comment: Use a query builder http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder Your code is wide open to sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution.

I transformed CrashFilters into an array (using encode) and used a findBy :

```
$crashes = $em->getRepository('Entities\Crash')
            ->findBy(array_filter($request->encode), null, self::LIMIT_RESULT);
```

array_filter to prevent the null value.

My function encode :

```
public function encode(){
        return [
            'dqaid' => $this->getDqaid(),
            'portal' => $this->getPortal(),
            'app_id' => $this->getAppId(),
            'app_version_id' => $this->getAppVersionId(),
            'reason' => $this->getReason(),
            'reason_hash' => $this->getReasonHash(),
            'brand' => $this->getBrand(),
            'model' => $this->getModel(),
            'os_version' => $this->getOsVersion(),
            'datecreated' => $this->getDatecreated()
        ];
    }
```

It works for now.